# tornado blocked by tight loop inside async function on windows but not linux

Tags: python, python-asyncio, tornado, hardware-interface

I'd like to run a http server and a USB-Serial button box key press watcher in the same script.
To poll the button box for a response, there is a loop endlessly polling "did anything happen yet." (`poll_for_response()` + `has_response()`)

On Linux, this goes as expected -- both components appear to respond independently.

On Windows, the function with the tight loop runs well but the http side is unresponsive. adding `asyncio.sleep()` with an impossibly small wait time to the inner loop unblocks http.

Is this expected? Is there a better way forward? Response timing precision is a concern.

---

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import asyncio
import sys
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application

# using pyxid2 and class wrapper IRL
DEV = CEDRUS_USB_SERIAL_BUTTON_BOX_FD2XXX

class HttpTTL(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, msg):
        self.write(f"{msg}")

def http_run():
    app = Application([('/(.*)', HttpTTL)])
    server = HTTPServer(app)
    server.listen(4444)

async def watch():
    while True:
        # TIGHT LOOP. polling for button box responses
        # percision timing is important
        while not DEV.has_response():
            DEV.poll_for_response()
            # needed on windows, not on linux?
            await asyncio.sleep(.0001)

        # have response ready to do things with it
        resp = DEV.get_next_response()
        print(resp)
        sys.stdout.flush()


async def main():
    # without sleep in watch() http is nonresponsive
    http_run()
    await asyncio.create_task(watch())

asyncio.run(main())
```